# How to create a custom API route in SocialEngine Zend

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I have created a new REST API module in SocialEngine which can be browsed via `http://server_address/mymodule` or `http://server_address/mymodule/index`. I have a controller class `Mymodule_IndexController` inside the`controllers` directory. It has a method `indexAction` in which I output some JSON response. It works.
The question is, how can I add another route and corresponding action e.g. `food/browse` in this module. I have already added the following routes inside `manifest.php`, but when I browse to `http://server_address/mymodule/browse`, the route is not resolved (Page not found error).

```
'routes' => array(       
    'food_general' => array(
        'route' => 'advancedrestapi/:controller/:action/*',
        'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'advancedrestapi',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
        'reqs' => array(
            'controller' => '\D+',
            'action' => '\D+',
        ),
    ),
```

How can I introduce new custom routes and corresponding PHP method to my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom route, you need to add a file with the same name as your 'action' and then .tpl extension. So, for the route in question (`'action'=>'browse'`), you will need to have a file as `application/modules/mymodule/views/scripts/index/browse.tpl`. The file can be empty.
Then, you will need to add a new method to your IndexController class `browseAction` (action + `Action`). Write your logic inside the method and you will be able to access the action via `http://server_address/mymodule/index/browse`.